# ¿Cómo funciona i -=- 1?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico, lógica

Hola he visto algunos memes sobre que 
`i -=- 1;`
es lo mismo que
`i++;`
Lo comprobé y si es así. Pero por qué. ¿Cómo es la lógica de esa instrucción?
Saludos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El que realmente mola es el último, pero está al revés. Debería ser `i=-~i`

Comment: Ahora que sabes como funciona, no lo uses ;-D

Answer (score 32, accepted):

reconstruyamos tu operación:

```
i-=-1;
```

sin espacios ya se ve de otra forma.. ahora ajustemos los espacios según los token del lenguaje (o por lo menos la mayoría de ellos)

```
i -= -1;
```

y qué nos queda? esto, se traduciría a lo siguiente:

```
i = i - (-1);
```

lo que es lo mismo que:

```
i = i + 1;
```

lo que es lo mismo que:

```
i += 1;
```

lo que equivale a:

```
i++;
```

Comment: No pensé que vería un meme explicado en SO :)

Comment: yo nunca vi el meme

Comment: Regla básica de multiplicación dé signos menos (-) por (x) menos (-) es igual (=) a más (+)

Comment: Gracias, ahora me queda mas claro. Disculpen pero edite la pregunta y puse el meme.

Comment: Tanto a la pregunta como a la respuesta le faltan un *detallito* importante: ¿ **De que lenguaje estamos hablando** ? Dudo mucho que un programador de `LUA` o de `Python` estén de acuerdo con esta respuesta.

Comment: Es verdad que el lenguaje debe influir. Pero creo que de manera general es bastante correcta la respuesta. Por lo menos lo probé en Java y funcionó tal cual. ¿Cual seria la diferencia en LUA y Python?

Comment: @Juanjo cuando una pregunta es lenguaje agnostica, quiere decir que implica muchos lenguajes. Ni todos, ni uno, si no varios. Definir una lista de lenguajes donde funciona no es el punto de la pregunta. Puede que en LUA o Python no anden, pero seguro andan en java, c# y c++... y seguro en muchos mas...

Comment: @AGHA En que ni Lua ni Python tienen los operadores `-=` ni `+=`. Sigo viendo la pregunta rara ... pero supongo que si, que me pasé de *quisquilloso*.

Comment: @Juanjo en ese caso, entonces tampoco entenderian el meme, con lo que no tiene sentido nada...

Comment: @Juanjo Python sí que tiene `-=` y `+=`, e incluso son redefinibles en tus propias clases. Y la operación `i-=-1` funciona como se ha descrito para `i` entero.

Comment: @Juanjo Los que Python no tiene son `++` y `--`.